# Adobe Air with WCF service

Tags: wcf, air

I want to communicate with Adobe Air with a WCF Client. I have created the WCF service.

I have Flex Builder 3.0, but how do I communicate the WCF service using Adobe Air? Please guide me.

Comment: Surely you'd communicate with the WCF service the same as any other web service?

Comment: Can you provide the steps Adobe air with WCF communication or can you provide the sample simple Adobe air with WCF?

Comment: -1 for ignoring the correct answer and marking your own, incorrect, answer

Answer (score 2):

To generate the proxy, click `File > Import > Flex Builder > WSDL` and select the WSDL url for your WCF service ("http://tempuri.org/v1/MyService.svc?wsdl").

A few things to be aware of:

- Give the proxy a unique package, like `org.tempuri.myService_v1`. The importer will generate classes like `Boolean` that will conflict if you import several services into the same package.
- The generated code has real problems with enumerations and Guids, so avoid both if you can. This may not be an issue with WCF 4 since it did significant updates in WSDL compatibility, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Is it possible in Flex Builder 3.0?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have a major product in production that uses WCF services from a Flex Builder 3 built solution.